# How are Javascript's sparse arrays constructed? What is placed in each index?

Tags: javascript, v8

I know this question has no practical usage, but I have read many different definitions of what sparse arrays are and I was wondering what the exact low level implementation of how these dynamic arrays are created.

Are sparse arrays an array of pointers? Or is it like an array of some kind of Struct node? Or is it some generic large space that can be filled with something small like a Char, or something big like a float?

Comment: It depends on the implementation.  But usually a hash table.

Comment: arrays are hash tables unless/until it can proven otherwise that there's a better fit. for example, in V8, even `[1,2,3]` will start life as a hash until the optimization routine realizes that a uIntArray would work better, and transparently converts it. if there's no upgrade available, it stays a hash.

Comment: I read not long ago that some engines switch automatically from array/vector to hash table when you use the sparse array features... Well, what dandavis said :)

Comment: it would probably go the other direction since starting with a normal would cause a type error

Comment: @dandavis: Are you sure about that? I was pretty certain that integer indices are always stored in an array (even on normal objects). This array will dynamically grow usually, but if the indices are becoming too sparse then probably that's the point where it switches to dictionary mode.

Comment: i may have used terms loose, my main point was that it's an abstract un-optimized representation unless/until it can be safely turned into a lower level, more efficient construct like an array of strings or floats or integers. that's why `r=[]; r.push(5);` causes a de-optimization in V8 that `r=[5];` would not experience (switching type from undefined to int). the actual way V8 stores that un-optimized array is indeed how you describe.

Answer (score 2):

If the array is only slightly sparse, the backing array is contiguous where hole indices have the `the_hole` value. The `the_hole` value is converted to `undefined` when dereferenced by the user. Indices with the `the_hole` value are also not reported as existing in the array by methods like `Object.keys`.

If the array is more sparse, it's simply a hash table with numbers as keys.

Unlike what is said in the comments, arrays are always assumed to be non-sparse and only converted to hash tables as a last resort rather than the other way around. That happens when you do something like define a custom property descriptor for an array index (never ever do that) or make the array too sparse.

Comment: Thanks for confirming my thoughts from the comments. Can you detail "too sparse"?

Comment: @Bergi Ok so basically arrays with less than 5000 elements are not checked for being too sparse when they are new. If they are old (e.g. survived 5 gc collections or so typically), then that limit is 500. If the array is bigger than this, then it is checked for a gap size of 1024. So distance between 2 successive elements being greater than 1024 is "too sparse".